# Implement MailNotifier

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I would like not to use Spring Boot Admin built-in `MailNotifier` but use an own implemented version. I suppose I would have to implement `AbstractEventNotifier` but how to avoid the use of the built-in `MailNotifier`?